# Custom Cell not rendering correctly on Xamarin.IOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am new to C# and I am experiencing a problem where a custom cell is not rendering correctly on IOS. I created a custom Renderer for Android and IOS. The android Renderer resizes the cell correctly but on IOS the cell just appear with all the fields cramp on a cell but the cell is not resized to fit all the fields. How Can I force the cell on IOS to resize and accommodate all the fields of a costume cell? The following is my code:

Common Cell Code

```
public class NativeCell : ViewCell
{
public static readonly BindableProperty HostNameProperty =
BindableProperty.Create ("HostName", typeof(string), typeof(NativeCell), "");

    public string HostName {
        get { return "HostName: " + (string)GetValue (HostNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue (HostNameProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty OSNameProperty = 
        BindableProperty.Create ("OSName", typeof(string), typeof(NativeCell), "");

    public string OSName
    {
        get { return "OS Name: " + (string)GetValue (OSNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue (OSNameProperty, value); }
    }


    public static readonly BindableProperty IPAddressProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("IPAddress", typeof(string), typeof(NativeCell), "");

    public string IPAddress
    {
        get { return "IP Address: " + (string)GetValue(IPAddressProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IPAddressProperty, value); }
    }


    public static readonly BindableProperty OnlineSinceProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("OnlineSince", typeof(string), typeof(NativeCell), "");

    public string OnlineSince
    {
        get { return "Online Since: " + (string)GetValue(OnlineSinceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OnlineSinceProperty, value); }
    }


    public static readonly BindableProperty ImageFilenameProperty = 
        BindableProperty.Create ("ImageFilename", typeof(string), typeof(NativeCell), "");

    public string ImageFilename {
        get { return (string)GetValue (ImageFilenameProperty); }
        set { SetValue (ImageFilenameProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Renderer and custome Cell on IOS

```
public class NativeiOSCell : UITableViewCell
{
UILabel hostName,osVersion, ipAdddress, onlineSince;
UIImageView imageView;

    public NativeiOSCell (NSString cellId) : base (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellId)
    {
        SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.Gray;

        ContentView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB (255, 255, 224);

        imageView = new UIImageView ();


        hostName = new UILabel () {
            Font = UIFont.FromName ("Cochin-BoldItalic", 15f),
            TextColor = UIColor.FromRGB (127, 51, 0),
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear
        };

        osVersion = new UILabel()
        {
            Font = UIFont.FromName("Cochin-BoldItalic", 15f),
            TextColor = UIColor.FromRGB(127, 51, 0),
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear
        };

        ipAdddress = new UILabel()
        {
            Font = UIFont.FromName("Cochin-BoldItalic", 15f),
            TextColor = UIColor.FromRGB(127, 51, 0),
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear
        };

        onlineSince = new UILabel()
        {
            Font = UIFont.FromName("Cochin-BoldItalic", 15f),
            TextColor = UIColor.FromRGB(127, 51, 0),
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear
        };

        ContentView.Add(hostName);
        ContentView.Add(osVersion);
        ContentView.Add(ipAdddress);
        ContentView.Add(onlineSince);

        ContentView.Add (imageView);
    }

    public void UpdateCell (string name, string os, string ip, string online, UIImage image)
    {
        hostName.Text = name;
        osVersion.Text = os;
        ipAdddress.Text = ip;
        onlineSince.Text = online;
        imageView.Image = image;
    }

    public override void LayoutSubviews ()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews ();


        //osVersion.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect (5, 55, ContentView.Bounds.Width - 63, 25);
        hostName.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect (100, 5,  250, 25);
        osVersion.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect (100, 100, 250, 25);
        ipAdddress.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(100, 200, 250, 25);
        onlineSince.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(100, 300, 250, 25);

        imageView.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect (5, 5, 50, 50);
    }
}

public class NativeiOSCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
{
static NSString rid = new NSString ("NativeCell");

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (Xamarin.Forms.Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
    {
        var x = (NativeCell)item;
        Console.WriteLine (x);

        NativeiOSCell c = reusableCell as NativeiOSCell;

        if (c == null) {
            c = new NativeiOSCell (rid);

        }

        UIImage i = null;
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (x.ImageFilename)) {
            i = UIImage.FromFile ("Images/" + x.ImageFilename + ".jpg");
        }
        c.UpdateCell (x.HostName, x.OSName, x.IPAddress, x.OnlineSince, i);

        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a custom renderer for this? From what I can tell here there's not a whole lot that you couldn't do in Xamarin.Forms only.

Comment: Hey! Would you mind hosting a sample project on GitHub? I would like to dig into the issue, and potentially file a bug with the engineering team if needed. As previously requested, it would be good to know what your are ultimately trying to accomplish, as a custom renderer may not be necessary

Comment: Hello, I am trying to  to  setup a custom cell to present these 4 fields and an Image on a cell, This is just one of the examples of the several custom cells I need to create. The costume cell that I need are basically presenting different fields and an image. I am really new to xamarin so I was not sure how to approach this problem. I read some of the documentation about creating custom cells and they talk about creating custom rederer. I was able to make the Andorid work  but IOS is my problem. I will post the project on Github a Little later and post the link. Thanks

Comment: I Created a repository under https://github.com/gduchate/CustomRenderer1

Comment: Hey! I was a doing a little more reading and I found that I can do what I need using ViewCell and customizing  its format. I will give it a try. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, that would seem to be a better way to go.